# Can we implement the random forest algorithm in convunational neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, random-forest

We can use random forest algorithm only for tabular data but cnn can be used for other various data types.so if we can somehow generate tabular data from cnn can we use it in random forest algo.

Answer (score 0):

There are some works on how to implement Decision trees or random forests with neural networks, see for example [Yang et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.06988.pdf) (2018). For the second part of your question, about if we can use randomforests on cnn data, it is also possible, consider for example using a pruned cnn to extract features from a given image, and to use a randomforest to classify them.